# Back Arrow Key is Random

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Lubuntu.

For whatever reason, the left arrow key will not work. At least, not consistently. I can go up, down, right, and backspace, but the left arrow key will work only on a seldom basis, otherwise it does nothing.

I checked out the preference settings for my keyboard and don't see anything relevant to input. At least, not to my knowledge. (I'm certainly a newb.)

How can I give my left arrow key life again?

Comment: You can check whether it works by running `xev` in terminal - look for something like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6586105/)

Comment: I tried that just now. Where do I look? It gave out *a lot* of data.

Comment: Look at what appears when you press the left key - try not to move the mouse, as that will provide input as well - like I said, look for something like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6586105/) :-)

Comment: Hmm. I tried it, and no, the left key doesn't work. It'll respond to all the other arrow keys, but not the left one.

Comment: Then it is very likely that this is a driver fault with Ubuntu, if it works with other OS - unless a hardware fault occurred around the same time...

Comment: I'm very ignorant on these computer matters. Would that mean it's essentially unsolvable within this version of Ubuntu? (I use the latest Lubuntu.)

Comment: A fresh re-install may solve it - you may want to check whether the key works in the Live disk first. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it may be a hardware issue, rather than a software issue. You should try connecting an external USB keyboard and see if its left arrow key works fine, and/or boot into a different OS (or even just the BIOS menu) and see if the left arrow key still has the same problem there.

Comment: I'm unsure, but I doubt it. I can't afford a USB keyboard, but if I recall right, the left arrow key worked fine when I was using Windows Vista and Puppy Linux, so Ubuntu is the odd one out, particularly since it's system-wide and not tied to any single program.

Comment: Oh. I read your question a second time and see that you already mentioned the OS thing. But yeah: Whenever I've booted up other OSes the left arrow key would work fine; it stopped all of the sudden when I switched to Lubuntu.